# How to set nonce attribute dynamically in React app , that uses Material UI, for the Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, content-security-policy

We would like to set nonce attribute for dynamically generate style attributes from material UI . We are using makeStyles function from material UI to inject css in individual components.

Is there a workaround for the same ?

Our react app is hosted inside a dotnet wrapper . And we are setting the CSP policy in startup.cs file.

**NOTE : We are not relaxing the CSP ploicy by removing the 'unsafe-inline' atrribute.
**
If anyone has come across this issue before I would really appreciate hearing.

We tried to add the nonce attribute in the starup.cs.